# Understanding RT patches organization for back porting

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to backport RT patch from 3.0 to 2.6.35 kernel. Using README file trying to understand how RT patches are organized at https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/3.0/. Can you help on the following.

1. I could see different -rt numbers for different kernel versions in older directotry.
   Ex: patch-3.0.3-rt12.patch.bz2, patch-3.0.4-rt13.patch.bz2 ---->  my doubht here is (a)rt changes for 3.0.3 is rt12 and the same rt changes for 3.0.4 kernel is rt13 or (b)while the kernel is changing from 3.0.3 to 3.0.4 the rt changes added from rt2 to rt3 without depending on the kernel changes).
2. In the incr directory I could see rt numbers are changing for the same kernel version.
   Ex: patch-3.0.4-rt13-rt14.patch.bz2, patch-3.0.4-rt14-rt15.patch.bz2, patch-3.0.6-rt16-rt17.patch.bz2, patch-3.0.6-rt17-rt18.patch.bz2 ----> what exactly it means.
3. I could see following content in README for incr directory, can you help to understand?

> - The incr directory contains patches that will move you from one
>     version to the next.(here one version to next means rt version or
>     kernel version?)
> - It only includes patches moving between stable releases. (i.e 3.0.4, >3.0.6 ....)
> - The changes between vanilla Linux stable releases will not have an  incremental patch.(not sure what it is?)

4. As per my understanding the kernel release follows as 3.0.rc1, 3.0.rc2,......,3.0.rcn and after all bug fixes it will be released as 3.0 . But I couldn't see any rt patch for 3.0 kernel in the top directory, only patch-3.0.101-rt130.patch.bz2 patch is available.